# How to get responsive design for images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap classes for designing my webpage.But image size and text size dragged while i minimizing the window.How to it?

```
<div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3">
<div class="panel panel-success" style="height:200px;">
<div class="panel-heading"><b>TIMESHEET</b></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
    <a href="@routes.Timesheets.showSelectPage()"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/tabImages/timesheet.png")" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Image" style="width:17%;"><p class="text-muted">Timesheet Processing</p>
    </a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.panel-success{
height:220px;
}
.panel-heading{
text-align:center;
font-size:22px;
padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.center-block{
 width:45%;
}
.panel-warning{
 height:200px;
}
```

Comment: i used <div class=" col-md-3  col-md-offset-1" style="margin-left:0px;"> like this.now text is not getting distorted.But when increase the size of the image ang minimize it ,getting image outside outside panel.

Comment: if possible try and make a fiddle. will help in finding out a solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using bootstrap , you may find help here [Response Images in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive)

If text is getting distorted, i'd recommend checking your bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

For your text I would suggest placing this in your body  `font-size:62.5%`

Then instead of using 22px, use `font-size:2.2rem;`

This should help  with the text. Now for you image try setting it's width in `%` Then it will scale nicely after resizing

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style: width: 17% from your img. img-responsive class from bootstrap should automatically take care of your image resizing. For the text part, as mentioned above, use % or media queries to define styles for different devices